# Kong Deck Ping fails to connect in git action workflow

Tags: github-actions, kong

I am trying to automate the Kong Deployment with the Deck tool, I am able to ping and sync the configurations manually but when I am trying to automate this flow with git actions deck ping command fails with "**request canceled while waiting for connection**".

**actions/main.yml**

```
name: Validate and Import OpenAPI on Push

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - name: Setup Deck
      uses: kong/setup-deck@v1.2.2
      with: 
        deck-version: 1.8.0
        
    - name: checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: Run Deck
      run: deck ping --kong-addr http://172.28.12.124:8001
```

** Build error **

[image]

I am able to get the response from curl but it fails to ping from git action. I am missing anything here?

[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It seems that you're using a GitHub-hosted machine to run the workflow. Can you make sure that the IP can be reached from anywhere and is not a private address? (172.16.xx.xx - 172.31.xx.xx is typically reserved for private networks)

Comment: Yes, I can access the IP from the browser/curl and it sends the response back

Comment: How and where do you deploy Kong? To add, accessing via your browser doesn't mean that It's accessible from GitHub, It could be because of the deployment or network.

Comment: Okay, I have deployed the Kong inside my local k8s cluster using minikube. I am new to K8s could you please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Allowing Connection from GitHub to access Kong (using lb to expose service) should do the trick (Finding your IP via what's my IP, for example)